# Failure writing file Log_File_Risk_Alert_Report : The permissions granted to user '' are insufficient for performing this operation

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

**Context:** I keep raising this error when I try to execute an SSRS Email or File Drop subscription - and I have no idea why. The empty string `''` seems to imply I need to add some specific user information but I have no idea where.

I was able to send a test email through the Database Mail wizard in the management studio. I noticed in the SQL Server `sysmail_event_log` record for that event the `last_mod_user` was `NTService\MSSQLSERVER`. But the failed subscription execution attempts are showing up under the `sa` in the `last_mod_user` I suspect something is at play between this discrepancy but idk how to fix it.

The error description also reads:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail
> server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 4 (2022-04-22T17:41:01).
> Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The SMTP server
> requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The
> server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail.
> [BN0P110CA0026.NAMP110.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]).  )

**Questions:** Can someone please assist?

[image]

Comment: Over time Microsoft is slowly reconfiguring services to require TLS 1.2 connections. My [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71120091/390122) related to DatabaseMail vs. Office365 might hold some clues. The `5.7.57` error suggests that the sending user may not be authorized to send mail through Office365 SMTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the account to the Local Admin of the Machine to fix the Operation.Mail one

Comment: The text after the sentence "Mail one" doesn't really make any sense